# Calculating haystack size of a string

Tags: math, passwords, complexity-theory

I want to create a poor-mans version of a password complexity checker. I determine the rough character set the password is using and its length. The search space would then be: charset ^ length. In order to compare this against a single value I want the smallest x that when used as the exponent of 2 is larger than the search space. In more mathy language I want this:

given a and b find the smallest x where a^b < 2^x;

My math sucks. Is there a quick and easy way to calculate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe my math doesn't suck quite that much.

```
  2^x == a^b
= define a = 2^c, c = 2loga
  2^x == 2^c^b
=
  2^x == 2^c*b
=
  x == c*b
=  
  x == 2loga * b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the equation by using logarithms. Taking the logarithms on both sides yields

```
x > b * log(a) / log(2)
```

If you want to find the smallest integer such that the equation holds we can round up the right hand side. In python this can be implemented as

```py
import math

def find_x(a, b):
    return math.ceil(b * math.log(a) / math.log(2))
```